# Collector method reference Java 8?

Tags: java

Suppose I have

```
void method(){
   Collector<Item> collector = ...
   List<Item> toBeCollected = ...
   toBeCollected.forEach(item -> collector.collect(item));
}
```

I have been doing this for now, however IntelliJ Idea keeps saying the `collector.collect(item)` can be replaced with a method reference. Any idea how I can do this espescially considering that `collector` is a reference from outside the Lambda?

Thanks

Comment: It's just `collector::collect`. (You can use an instance as the left-hand side of the operator.)

Comment: @chrylis, I tried that too BUT it then says `void is not a functional interface`

Comment: Nevermind I've got it thanks @chrylis

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ most likely suggests to use:

```
toBeCollected.forEach(collector::collect);
```

You can trigger this code refactor by pressing [Alt+Enter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html)  on the problematic code to open intentions actions menu.